# SQL using more simple indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-performance

my questions are **What indexes are used? In what order? Why?** in following sample

Query:

```
SELECT House 
FROM myTable 
WHERE 1=1 
 and City='myCity' 
 and Street='myStreet'
 and Color='myColor'
```

Indexes:

```
Ind1: City
Ind2: Street
Ind3: Color
Ind4: Street,Color
```

Comment: Indexes depend on a lot of things, and as it stands this question is too broad. If you have a real database table, with x number of rows, some sample queries, execution plans for slow performing queries and a bunch of other information then you might have a question that is answerable.

Comment: And what is the purpose of 1=1? Sorry... there is no purpose.

Comment: @Tanner - The purpose is to make it easier to comment out individual where clauses, other than that, there indeed isn't any purpose. I tend to use it too.

Comment: @Tanner: for easy commenting

Comment: I understand that in this common sample you cannot say which index will be used. So it depends on data?

Comment: The question is not "What should I use", but "What indexes are used (by SQL server)". I expected some hint of behaviour of the server...

Comment: @Tanner - It can be useful when where clause is concatenated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on... The server might have statistics, so it will choose the index which has the most effective filtering like:

if `City='myCity' returns 100`

if `Street='myStreet' returns 1000`

if `Color='myColor'  returns 10000`

element, then City index will be used. This logic is valid for composite indexes as well.
The optimizer will try to get the smallest set first then the other filters will be applied on this.

This requires uptodate statistic, otherwise the wrong index might be used.

Comment: Yes, I update statistics nightly (it is enough for the project). I understand, that I should build the index from the smallest set first, but If I have the indexes already set (an old project) as in my sample above, which of the indexes will be used? Is it possible to use more indexes?

Comment: It is possible but might not be worse than not using it. Like city='myCity' would return 10 element, then it is cheaper to go through all the records in memory than reading index from street and color indexes from filesystem. You can give hints to the optimizer which index to pick up. Without knowing what data and what stats you have, it is impossible to find out which index will be used